# determine size of file for buffer allocation in c

Tags: c, file, malloc, eof, feof

This snippet of code I wrote is supposed to traverse through
a file and increment the size-counter each-time it goes `+1`
character:

```
while (fgetc(input) != EOF)
    size++; 

if (feof(input)) {
    buff = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1); 
}
```

while the end of the file is not reached size is being incremented. If `EOF-> feof==true` and the the buffer-size
can be determined.

Just wanted to know if it is possible that way or if there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Just omit the `if(feof(input))` condition. It is not needed.(unless you want to differentiate between errors and eof, which is seldomly needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `size` is initialized to `0` before the loop and `input` is at the beginning of the stream, the loop will correctly determine the number of bytes that can be read from the file.

Testing for `feof()` after the loop distinguishes end-of-file and read-error conditions. It is usually not necessary to make this distinction, so you can remove this test.

`malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1)` allocates the correct number of bytes to read the file as a C string, but the expression is incorrect: it should be either `sizeof(char) * (size + 1)` or just `size + 1` as `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Note that you will need to set the null terminator explicitly as `malloc()` does not initialize the block it allocate.

Note also the some streams, such a terminals, may not be seekable, so this method may fail if you need to rewind the stream to read the bytes.

Note finally that `size` may be smaller than the length of the file on legacy systems that use 2 bytes for end of line markers such as MS/DOS and Windows.

Comment: thank you! Im new to programming in C-> would using calloc instead of malloc solve the problem with the null-terminator that has to be set explicitly? And regarding the terminals that may not be seekable-> I think the funciton rewind() would solve that too- as it resets the pointer to the beginning of the buffer.

Comment: `calloc()` indeed initializes the block to all bits zero, hence no need to set the null terminator.  Regarding `rewind()`, there is no difference between `fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_SET)` and `rewind()`, although `fseek()` does return a success indicator, whereas `rewind()` is a void function, but this does not mean that it always succeeds. If more characters were read from the stream than can fit in the stream buffer, the stream must be seekable for `rewind()` to reset the stream to the beginning of file. Besides terminals, pipes are not seekable handles.

Answer (score 1):

Using ftell() function size can be determined, as

```
fseek( input, 0, SEEK_END );
size = ftell( input);
```

Then set the pointer to the file beginning,

```
fseek( input, 0, SEEK_SET );
```

Comment: C17 **7.21.9.4 the `ftell` function:** *The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.*